# Is this problem Multiclass or MultiLabel?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I am working on a coursework that asks me to take an image and classify it in one of the 15 scenes. An image can be only 1 class at a time. So that makes it a multiclass problem right?

How could one change the problem and make it into a multilabel?

Comment: What do you mean by "multilabel"?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a multilabel problem, if you assign several scenes to one image (or none), and not only exactly one. This is the difference between multilabel and multiclass, to each observation more than one target class can be assigned instead of only one like in multiclass classification.